# How to make MySQL result set the same as specified?

Tags: mysql

```
Select * from table where id in ($id_list)...
```

How to make the result the same order as specified in `$id_list` ?

If `$id_list='2,1,5...'` then the result set should be in the same order

Comment: if you already has the order `2,1,5`, how hard for your to generate results based on that order ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE id IN (1,5,10) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,5,10')
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by 'order of result'? Above query order result rows as defined in `FIND_IN_SET` instead of ascending or descending order.

Comment: Must put quotes around the $idlist

Answer (score 1):

you need to order by with switch case

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9)
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 3 THEN 1
                 WHEN 6 THEN 2
                 WHEN 1 THEN 3
                 WHEN 8 THEN 4
                 WHEN 9 THEN 5
         END
```

read more details on

[MySQL ORDER problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678196/mysql-order-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id IN ($id_list)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, $id_list)
```

Using `FIELD()` is better then using `FIND_IN_SET()`, Since they are compared as numbers.