# Sorting all results by specified field from database

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have data in my table that is defined by "locale" key that represents language that I need to sort all fields by.

I managed to do that, but it groups just first field in a table. I need to group sort all of the fields that are defined in "en" in one, "de" in the other. That is searched by getLocale().

[image]

Like in the image above I need them grouped by "en" value, "ru" value.

My code:

```
 $forPack = $this->getMyRepository()->findAll();

    $result = array();

    foreach($forPack as $key => $value){
        $locale = $value->getLocale();
        if(!isset($result[$locale])) $result[$locale] = array();
        $result[$locale] = array($key => $value);
    }


    dump($result);die;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL result set the same as specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026275/how-to-make-mysql-result-set-the-same-as-specified)

Comment: No, it's not. I have a problem pulling it up trough array. @SuRo

Comment: Looks like you missing `[]` after the array assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$result[$locale][] = $value;
```

Instead of

```
$result[$locale] = array($key => $value);
```